# Clear preview window in media foundation

Tags: camera, preview, ms-media-foundation

Is it possible to clear a preview window after preview from camera is done? I am using MFCaptureEngine, calling m_pPreview->SetRenderHandle(m_hwnd) to render the video. But when I stop the video I am not able to draw on the window. There remains a last frame from the camera. I need to fill the window by black brush and draw some text, but the image from the camera cannot be overdrawn.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear understand from you answer what is it `MFCaptureManager`, but by code `SetRenderHandle(m_hwnd)` I see that you use `IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetRenderHandle`. So, I can say that I had faced with similar problem some time ago, and it is related with difference between of the old window system which exist from WinXP and current window system from Vista. Code sets window context to the renderer by calling `IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetRenderHandle` - for IMFCapturePreviewSink it is DirectX11 - and DirectX11 has got FULL access to the window and it is switched to current window system. As a result, any calling `fill the window by black brush and draw some text` which is done by old Windows API from Win95-XP generation do nothing - because window handler context is LOCKED by DirectX11.

There are three ways for resolving of this problem:

1. Write the new UI by the new Microsoft DirectComposition GUI API which is based on DirectX11 and set it to [IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetRenderSurface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfcaptureengine/nf-mfcaptureengine-imfcapturepreviewsink-setrendersurface).
2. Create EVR Media Sink by [MFCreateVideoRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/evr/nc-evr-mfcreatevideorenderer) - it creates DirectX9 video renderer which is compatible with old Windows API from Win95-XP generation, and set this `IMFMediaSink` in  [IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetCustomSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfcaptureengine/nf-mfcaptureengine-imfcapturepreviewsink-setcustomsink).
3. Create code of the video renderer on DirectX9 base - for example  [MFCaptureD3D/device.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureD3D/device.cpp), and draw raw IMFSample from callback [IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetSampleCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfcaptureengine/nf-mfcaptureengine-imfcapturepreviewsink-setsamplecallback).

Regards.

Comment: The second option seems the easiest way to me. But I don't know how to call the MFCreateVideoRenderer function

Comment: @radimoid If you would like modify code with Media Foundation framework - you must research it. For example, read book [developing_microsoft_media_foundation_applications.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9pVRwN4TMxNeW15TDVJXzB4MEE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: All I need to know is the GUID for mentioned DirectX9 video renderer which I am not able to find on the internet nor in the book.

Comment: It does not need special GUID - it needs only GUID of `IMFMediaSink` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented it this way:

```
// Sink
CComPtr<IMFCaptureSink> pSink;
m_pEngine->GetSink(MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_SINK_TYPE_PREVIEW, &pSink);

CComPtr<IMFMediaSink> pCustomSink;
::MFCreateVideoRenderer(IID_IMFMediaSink, (void**)&pCustomSink);

CComPtr<IMFCapturePreviewSink> pPreviewSink;
pSink.QueryInterface(&pPreviewSink);
pPreviewSink->SetCustomSink(pCustomSink);

// preview
pSink.QueryInterface(&m_pPreview); // or pPreviewSink.QueryInterface(&m_pPreview)
m_pPreview->SetRenderHandle(m_hwndPreview);
```

But the behaviour is still the same (the screen cannot be redrawn after the preview is stopped).

Comment: "But the behaviour is still the same" - because code of `IMFCapturePreviewSink` still use window handler by `m_pPreview->SetRenderHandle(m_hwndPreview);` and window handler is locked be DirectX11 - for your purpose code must set window handler to `IMFMediaSink`. I advise you spend time on learning of Media Foundation development.

Comment: Are you sure MFCreateVideoRenderer is the right choice. I didn't find any possibility to set hwnd to IMFMediaSink. I tried MFCreateVideoRendererActivate which has a hwnd as its argument. But MF returns 0xc00d36b9 as a hresult during starting preview (receivent in event callback). Sorry to bother you but i am doing nothing but studying MF and still not able to connect all circumstances together. Eg. how can I set hwnd to IMFMediaSink. There's no method for it. I didn't find on the internet I didn't find in the pdf.

Comment: I advise you try the third way - Create code of the video renderer on DirectX9 base - for example [MFCaptureD3D/device.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/1d363ff4bd17d8e20415b92e2ee989d615cc0d91/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureD3D/device.cpp), and draw raw IMFSample from callback [IMFCapturePreviewSink::SetSampleCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfcaptureengine/nf-mfcaptureengine-imfcapturepreviewsink-setsamplecallback).